# Is there an in-world explanation why Aloy needs to learn skills again

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn, horizon-forbidden-west

I just finished playing Horizon: Zero Dawn on PC. While waiting for a PC version of Forbidden West, or ability to buy PlayStation 5, I have read the reviews and it looks like in Forbidden West Aloy needs to learn skills she knew in Zero Dawn.

Is it true? And if it is, is there any explanation inside the game world why? Loss of shards and equipment is easy to accept, but loss of skills hurts my suspension of disbelief.

I believe if there's an explanation it needs to be at the beginning, if I'm wrong please keep answers as spoiler free as possible.

Comment: Not really a fully answer, but as I see it, it's not that she's re-learning her skills, she is *enhancing* them. Sure, there are some minor skills that are repeated from Zero Dawn, but (if I'm not mistaken) a lot of combat-related abilities (like silent strike or strike from above) are available at the start of the game

Comment: @Wondercricket but double notch or luring enemies seems to be missing, and ability to set traps and wires is limited and you need to learn it again to lift the limit.

Comment: Is there any indication that the canon Aloy learned all of the available skills from Zero Dawn? Or are there skills that she is definitely shown in-canon as possessing that are missing now?

Comment: @ChrisHayes I don't know if there even is "canon" for this game besides scripted events. And in the world of save imports it doesn't need to matter - look at Witcher series, where you could import one save all the way through all the games.

Comment: I don't think there is, it's just for game balance. Just a speculation, but since Aloy lost her equipment, maybe some skills are re-learnt because she is using them on different weapons from ZD.

Comment: Does Horizon: Forbidden West offer save importing? I'm not sure how it's relevant that an entirely different game series does, if not. The writers undoubtedly have a canon they're working from, though whether it's made apparent to the player what that canon is, I couldn't say.

Comment: If Horizon: Forbidden West does not offer save importing, then it's conscious decision of the game developers, that leads to Aloy losing some skills between installments. Sentiment about "canon" is grossly outdated. There's no need for "canon" in videogames and there wasn't for decades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just started playing Forbidden West, and the answer is no.

Aloy's skills or abilities are not mentioned in the first few hours of the game (15h played) in any of the main story quests or side quests.

Most of the in-game story and dialog is focused on the main storyline of the game, and follows on from Aloy saving Meridian in the Battle of the Alight.

The only thing which might fit this question, is that early in the main campaign Aloy's spear is destroyed and she is given a new one, but there is no dialog about abilities in the cutscene.